# File download through Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a backend that I set up to return a file through setting the header

```
Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=somefile.csv
```

It works directly in the browser and downloads the file immediately upon invoking the URL that points to that resource.

My goal is to have a button in an Angular 2 template. When the user clicks that button, I'd need to collect some data from the client-side (some IDs) and send it to the server to invoke that file download URL.

I'd like the user to stay on the same page and not have any new tabs open up but simply have the file start downloading (just like when the URL is invoked directly).

It will need to be done through a **POST request** because I can have quite a bit of data to send to identify what resource needs to be downloaded.

What does the call on the Angular 2 side look like for this? I tried a couple of things but I am obviously on the wrong path.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 9):

I had a similar issue when i was trying to download a PDF file which my Node server was sending. I was making a GET request on my server with some id details.
This is what worked for me.

Function Calling my service

```
printBill(receiptID) {
this.BillingService.printBill(receiptID)
    .subscribe(res => {
        saveAs(res,"InvoiceNo"+receiptID+".pdf");
        let fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(res);
        window.open(fileURL);
    })
}
```

Service

```
printBill(billID) {
    return this.http.get('/billing/receipt/'+billID, 
                   { responseType: ResponseContentType.Blob })
      .map((res) => {
            return new Blob([res.blob()], { type: 'application/pdf' })
        })
}
```

And dont forget to import ResponseContentType

Hope this helps you

Comment: Where is `saveAs` defined? And what does it do?

Comment: saveAs() is used to save the files on the client side that the server returns.  It is from FileSaver.js. Here is the git link https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/

Comment: I'm not too familiar with blobs but this loads the entire content into memory and is therefore not suitable for gigantic downloads, right?

Answer (score 4):

i have implemented it like this.

i have a service requesting file download. The response return a url, which is on amazon s3. This is a zip file containing what i want to download.

the below works on all browsers.

in your controller

```
requestDownload() {

this.downloadservice.downloadImages(obj)
      .subscribe(
        response => this.download(response )
      );

}

// res is an object
download(res){ 
    var link = document.createElement("a");
    link.download = "a";
    link.href = res.link;
    document.body.appendChild(link);
    link.click();

     }
```

downloadservice file

```
downloadImages(body): Observable<any>{

        let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
        let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
        return this.http.post("/Camera51Server/getZippedImages", body, options)
            .map((res:Response) => res.json())
            .catch(this.handleError);
    }
```

if you like i can give you a link to the repository.

Comment: Thanks, but that's kind of going around what I am actually trying to see how to get done. Plus, it requires more server-side work to somehow identify the previous request associated with the new one. Remember, I am sending tons of data to identify what needs to be downloaded, so I need that POST. It would be a bit hacky for me to return a URL and then have the browser request that URL again and store off those results somewhere... I need it to happen all in one call and I wanted to know what Angular 2 (http.post call) would look like.

Comment: This worked perfectly fine for me:

`var link = document.createElement("a");
    link.download = "a";
    link.href = res.link;
    document.body.appendChild(link);
    link.click();`

Comment: @ShivamMaheshwari that doesn't work if you need an access token to get the image

Comment: @chris31389: Yes, but it does beautifully work when you hit the API to get the image as a URL, and then let the user to download the file (which was my use case)