# Angular 4 app rendering JSON as Server

Tags: json, angular, render

I made an Angular app and I wondering if its possible that Angular send JSON information like a server.

For exemple I'd like that when we access an URL of my app 'localhost:4200/test', the answer is an JSON and not a HTML page.
In other words, I want to be able to collect data with POSTMAN when I request an route of my Angular 4 app.

Thank for any informations.

P.S: I'm not sure that "RENDER" is the right term because when I look for "Angular render JSON" it's always about display a JSON in an HTML page :/

Comment: why would you want to do that with angular or any other front end framework?

Comment: I know it's a bit special it's a matter of security, to be clear, let's imagine we have :
1 API & 2 fronts
ONLY **FRONT1** had acces to the **API** and I want to call the **API** from **FRONT2** so my idea was : **FRONT2** request **FRONT1** who request **API**

Comment: Take a look at [this 'problem'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43029562/file-download-through-angular-2). Yours sounds the same, however you would like a mime type of `application/json`.

Comment: @Rick : It's the same because I don't want to GET or POST from my Angular app, but I want GET or POST from another front TO my angular app. And I will look for the MIME type if something can help me :)

Answer (score 0):

I could be wrong, but to my knowledge this is not possible. You want your client/browser application to behave like a server. This is not possible as you cannot setup a socket listener in a browser.
If you host your application in a shell like [electron](https://electron.atom.io/) it would be possible to start a nodejs server on the local machine. However technically this isn't your angular application any longer.

Comment: That's what I was afraid ..
In that case I will try to make the API request from **FRONT1** then send directly the HTML component to **FRONT2**